# Android cannot connect bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm making an app to connect bluetooth device from my android phone.

There is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SETTINGS = 2;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button connectButton;
    private ListView watchListView;

    private String[] availableWatches = {"Watch 1", "Watch 2", "Watch 3", "Watch 4"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        watchListView = findViewById(R.id.watchListView);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth permissions not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        availableWatches = new String[pairedDevices.size()];
        String[] availableWatchAddresses = new String[pairedDevices.size()];

        int index = 0;
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            availableWatches[index] = device.getName();
            availableWatchAddresses[index] = device.getAddress();
            index++;
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, availableWatches);
        watchListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        watchListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedWatchAddress = availableWatchAddresses[position];
                connectToWatch(selectedWatchAddress);

            }
        });

        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkPermissions();
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            connectToWatch(null);
        }
    }

    private void connectToWatch(final String watch) {
        if (watch != null) {
            final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            final BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(watch);

            final UUID sppUuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

            Thread connectThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth permissions not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            return;
                        }

                        BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(sppUuid);
                        socket.connect();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected to " + watch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


                        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        String message = "Hello, watch!";
                        outputStream.write(message.getBytes());

                        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
                        final String receivedMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Received message: " + receivedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        socket.close();

                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to connect to " + watch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            connectThread.start();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                connectToWatch(null);
            } else {
                textView.setText("Permission denied. Please enable the Body Sensors permission in the Settings.");
                connectButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It block on the socket.connect but cannot understand why it do this, tried with multiple device, never work.

It automaticly catch an IOException

Thanks for your help

Tried to use multiple device, with thread and without